# Logging in Ruby on Rails in Production Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, production

I would like to view some variables in controller, it tried the following:

`Rails.logger.debug "Year: #{Time.now.year}"`

`puts "Year: #{Time.now.year}, Month: #{@month}"`

where can I see the output for Logger or Puts in production mode?  Do I need so set something up to view these somewhere?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The normal log level in production is `info`, so `debug` logs are not shown.
Change your logging to

```
Rails.logger.info "Year: #{Time.now.year}"
```

to show it in `production.log`.

Alternatively (but not a good idea) you can raise the logging level in `/config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

**Update** Rails 4.2:

Now the default debug level in all environments is `:debug` (as @nabilh mentioned).
If you want you production environment less chattery, you can reset your log level in `/config/environments/production.rb` to the former `:info`:

```
config.log_level = :info
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the lower the log level, the more resources used in production as [mentioned in docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#impact-of-logs-on-performance)

Answer (score 9):

While I believe @martin-m is right that you probably don't want to clutter your logs by using `config.log_level = :debug` in `/config/environments/production.rb`, I believe the default logging level in *all* environments is `debug` as of Rails 4.2. So `debug` logs (and all levels up) will be shown in production unless you specify otherwise.

So in response to your question, you can now write:

`Rails.logger.debug "Year: #{Time.now.year}"` and see the results in `/log/production.log`.

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels) for more detailed documentation. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels) is the documentation for Rails 4.1 for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a production app that you may need to temporarily change log levels, you might want to use an environment variable to be able to set level without modifying code and redeployment, though your app would need to be restarted, you could take this approach:

config/environment/production.rb

```rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
#...
  log_level = :info #default state
  [:debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal, :unknown].each do |level|
    if ENV['LOG_LEVEL']&.to_sym == level
      log_level = level
    end
  end
 config.log_level = log_level
#...
end
```