# How to print logs on AWS for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have an application deployed on AWS with Nginx. I want to access logs, I tried `/etc/nginx/logs` but it always shows old logs. I also changed `config.log_level = :info` to `config.log_level = :debug` but it did not work. Is there any way to write logs on my custom file rather than access.log?

```
Production.rb
config.log_level = :info
RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new('log/staging.log')
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824355/logging-in-ruby-on-rails-in-production-mode

Comment: Why is log file name is `staging.log` for production ?  If you want to see application logs, it is under `app_directory/log/production.log`, or if you want to see nginx access log, ideally it will be under `/var/log/nginx/access.log`. Similarly nginx error log will be under `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: yes i checked /var/log/nginx/access.log but still there is old logs

Comment: Is the application running without any error ? You can watch live logs by using tail command: `tail -f /var/log/nginx/*.log`. Check this while accessing the application to see what is happening behind.

Comment: how will i get the logs if any form is submitted? i tried tail -100 /var/log/nginx/access.log but its not showing the logs

Comment: i tried   config.log_level = :info
  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new but still access.log is blank

Comment: Comment out the `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` line and check. This is used for test environment to see the logs in the console instead of writing it to a file. Access logs as: `tail -f app_dir/log/production.log`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.